# Conditionally create a task definition in ECS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk, boto

I have a boto3 script, which updates(create new revision) of ECS task definition and update the ECS service with the new task definition.

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client("ecs", region_name="us-east-1")

task_def_resp = client.register_task_definition(
    containerDefinitions=[<some_container_definitions>],
    executionRoleArn="arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    family= "AWSSampleApp2",
    networkMode="awsvpc",
    requiresCompatibilities= ["FARGATE"],
    cpu= "256",
    memory= "512")
...
...
update_svc_resp = client.create_service(
    cluster="xxxxxxxx", 
    serviceName="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    taskDefinition=task_def_resp.get('taskDefinition').get('taskDefinitionArn'),
    desiredCount=1,
    networkConfiguration={
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'subnets': ['xxxxxxxxxxx'],
            'securityGroups': ["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
        }
    },
    launchType='FARGATE',
)
...
...
```

The code works perfectly fine. But, even if there is no change in task definition, A new revision(version) is **always created** whenever I call this script.

My thought here is, **Is it possible to compare the task definition(find if the task defintion contains any changes) and create the new revision only if it contains some changes?**

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you switch from boto3 to something that manages state like terraform, it will handle the comparison for you.

Comment: @jordanm Yes, but terraform has it's own limitation(for eg: it will deregister the old task defintion version after the new one is applied, which affects our rollback process). So, we cannot use terraform. I am just looking if we can use some comparison in python script itself.

Comment: That appears to no longer be the case as of two weeks ago. They added a new `skip_destroy` attribute to task definitions. Does not appear docs have updated yet https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/258

Comment: oh woow.... it's a super feature. I will test it.